# Multiple Hosts vs Services in Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, web-applications

I'm running multiple web-apps on multiple ports. And I'm wondering what's the real difference between running multiple Hosts in the same Service, and running multiple Services with separate Hosts.

I know this can be used to share Connectors, but there any other reason on is better than the other ?

**Config 1 : Multiple Hosts**

```
        <Engine>
            //APP 1
            <Host>
                <Context .... />
            </Host>
            //APP 2
            <Host>
                <Context .... />
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

**Config 2 : Multiple Services**

```
<Server>
    //APP 1
    <Service>
        <Connector ... />
        <Connector ... />

        <Engine>
            <Host>
                <Context .... />
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
    //APP 2
    <Service>
        <Connector ... />
        <Connector ... />

        <Engine>
            <Host>
                <Context .... />
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only really good reason to have separate `<Service>`s is if you want to have a `<Connector>` that will (or will not) serve a specific subset of `<Host>`s or (as a consequence) `<Context>`s.

Comment: Additional configuration will definitely increase memory usage (because you will have separate `<Connector>` and `<Engine>`, `<Host>`, etc. things configured in memory). I'm not sure if `<Executor>s` are shared across `<Service>s`, and the `<Executor>` is where your memory is really used because of all the threads that are created.

Comment: As for performance, your performance will decrease slightly if you use multiple `<Host>s` (because each request needs to be matched against all the possible virtual hosts in an engine) but probably not multiple `<Service>s` (unless you have multiple hosts in those engines, too).